# Не загружается Ubuntu 16.04 после добавления дополнительной оперативной памяти

Tags: ubuntu

У меня стояло 2GB (1 плашка)
Я добавил ещё одну такую-же плашку на 2GB во второй слот
После этого Ubuntu перестала загружатся, но GRUB и BIOS работает
Возможно ли как-то это исправить чтобы я мог поставить 2 плашки?

Comment: укажите параметры обеих плашек. попробуйте поменять местами, если не получится, то следует подобрать одинаковые параметры плашек озу. у вас, вероятно, старая модель компьютера (контроллера), не умеющая работать с разными плашками памяти.

Comment: Да я пробовал менять их местами, но ноутбук правда старый

Comment: Но в самом ноуте есть 2 слота

Comment: После того как я поменял их местами ничего не заработало

Comment: а отдельно новая плата сама по себе работает?

Comment: Да работает хорошо

Comment: значит разные платы, увы. надо одинаковые ставить.

Comment: приведите их названия

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: попробуйте проверить еще так. работу обеих плашек на втором контакте, если не заработает, то может закисли контакты, то аккуратно по-притереть плашку. может заработает.